# Using $http as a function parameter - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb

I'm trying to use this AngularJS material chip.
(CONTACT CHIP - With auto-complete)
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/chips

And it has a different structure of what I'm used to. I want to adapt to get the contacts from my mongodb with $http, like:

```
$http.get("/contacts").success(function(response) {
          contacts = response;
});
```

But in their Angular Material code example is like this:

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])
      .controller('ContactChipDemoCtrl', DemoCtrl);
  function DemoCtrl ($q, $timeout) { 
...
 function loadContacts() {
  var contacts = [
    'Marina Augustine',
    'Oddr Sarno',
    'Nick Giannopoulos',
    'Narayana Garner',
    'Anita Gros',
    'Megan Smith',
    'Tsvetko Metzger',
    'Hector Simek',
    'Some-guy withalongalastaname'
  ];
}
...
```

How can I use $http as a parameter for the DemoCtrl function? To get the contacts from db

Comment: where is the codpen link?

Comment: Are you just asking how Dependency Injection works with Angular ? I suggest you take a look at the docs https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Comment: @Sajeetharan click in the link above and go to CONTACT CHIP, there is a codepen icon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MyModule.controller("DemoController", DemoCtrl);

DemoCtrl.$inject = ['$http'];

function DemoCtrl ($http) {
     $http.get("/contacts").success(function(response) {
      contacts = response;
});
```

Above is the preferred way to setup a controller because it doesn't use an anonymous function rather than:

```
MyModule.controller("DemoController", ['$http', function($http) {
     $http.get("/contacts").success(function(response) {
      contacts = response;
}]);
```

Comment: i'm gonna try it here

Comment: Also - @charlietfl is right - you should also inject $scope and set
    $scope.contacts = response.data;

Comment: Onde question @Booza in my function DemoCtrl there is some parameters DemoCtrl($q,$timeout). When I inject $http this should now be the first parameter, right !?

Comment: Whatever the order of the strings are, that should be the order of the parameters. It doesn't matter as long as they match up.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning response data to variable `contacts` which has no angular scope context

If you are using $scope as your data model for view it would be

```
$http.get("/contacts").then(function(response) {
          $scope.contacts = response.data;
});
```

Or if using controllerAs alias in view:

```
var vm = this
$http.get("/contacts").then(function(response) {
          vm.contacts = response.data;
});
```

Also need to inject `$http` in controller

Comment: This I know. The question is, how can I use the $http dependency inside the DemoCtrl function, or as a parameter...

Comment: You simply inject it. I guess I don't understand problem